# Why was Baelfire sent back with everyone when Regina tore the curse scroll?

Tags: plot-explanation, once-upon-a-time

I don't understand why Baelfire got sent back to the Enchanted forest with everyone in S0311 after Regina tore the curse scroll, "canceling the curse".

It doesn't make sense to me. He wasn't in "Story Brooke" in the first place suggesting that he wasn't in the enchanted forest when the curse originally struck.

Comment: This exact question was asked and answered/discussed on the [Science Fiction & Fantasy SE](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/47310/why-did-baelfire-have-to-go-back-when-the-curse-was-destroyed).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the episode ["Going Home"](http://onceuponatime.wikia.com/wiki/Going_Home/Transcript) (3x11):

> **Leroy:** It's here!! The curse, it's here! It's coming from all sides!
>   There's no escape.
>   *(Neal hugs a worries Henry.)*
>   **David:** It's not too late. We can still stop it, right? Regina?
>   **Regina:** Yes. Yes.
>   **Emma:** W-what's the price? Gold said there is a price. What is our price?
>   **Regina:** *(Turns around to face the group)* It's not our price. It's mine.
>   **Emma:** What are you talking about?
>   **Regina:** It's what I felt when I... first held it. I have to say goodbye to the thing I love most.
>   **Emma:** *(Turns to look at Henry, who approaches forward to stand beside her) (To Regina)* Henry?
>   **Regina**: I can never see him again. I have no choice. I have to undo what I started.
>   **Mary Margaret:** *(In realization)* The curse that brought us to Storybrooke?
>   **Regina:** That created Storybrooke. It doesn't belong here, and neither do any of us.
>   **David:** Breaking the curse destroys the town.
>    **Regina:** It will wend out of existence as though it were never here. And everyone will go back to where they are from. Prevented from ever returning.
>   **Emma:** We'll go back to the Enchanted Forest?
>   **Regina:** All of us. Except Henry. He will stay here because... he was born here.
>   **Emma:** Alone?
>   **Regina:** No, you will take him. Because you're the savior. And you were created to  break the curse. And once again, you can escape it.

So, according to show canon, Neal ended up back in the Enchanted Forest because he was born there. The destroying of the curse affected everyone inside of Storybrooke's town limits whether or not they were brought there by the curse. Hook was also spirited away because he was not born in the Land Without Magic though he wasn't affected by the curse either. Emma (who was the exception since she was born in the Enchanted Forest) and Henry left the town limits/were over the town line before the curse smoke hit them as well.

Comment: Wait, wasn't Hook born in England? Where are Hook and his brother from?

Comment: According to Adam Horowitz's(exec producer) [Tweet](https://mobile.twitter.com/AdamHorowitzLA/status/394622657712242688): " hook is in a fairy tale realm navy. Not from our world". Remember he is Killian Jones, not James Hook.

Answer (score -2):

I realize I'm 4 years behind but...

Pan's curse was that everyone in SB lose their memories and be ruled by him. Regina destroyed the curse thus reversing her original curse.  So, Neal would not have been taken by the undoing because he wasn't transported by the original curse. Basically, sending Neal back was continuity error and a clumsy way for the writers to reincarnate Gold.